# How to call an object the following day when clearly, a user is not running your app

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, avfoundation, nsfilemanager

I'm still very much on the beginning of my iOS journey and I'm messing around with AVFoundation by using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer. I'm saving the files with the following lines of code:

```
- (NSURL *)urlPath {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMdyyyy+HHMMss"];

    NSString *nowString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

    NSString *destinationString = [[self documentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a", nowString]];

    NSURL *destinationURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationString];

    return destinationURL;
}

- (NSString *)documentsPath {
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    return documentsPath;
}

-(NSDictionary *)getRecorderSettings {
  NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
  [recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

  return recordSettings;
}
```

and recording by:

```
self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[self urlPath] settings:[self getRecorderSettings] error:&error];
```

I know how to get the player to go into the documents folder to play each of the files; however, I want the app to only have access to an audio file only if 24 hours has passed by. So ideally, something like a uitableviewcell being created after 24 hours, instead of right after the recording. I have a general idea of how I want to do it, but I'm also feeling a bit confused about it because of the fact that if a user were to exit the app, how would the app know that 24 hours has gone by?

I'm thinking that I need to give it another date field like an  `NSDate *showAt`property and set a parameter in which the audio objects that will show up are files after a specific date/time. Anytime a file has been created, I'd like for parse to send a push notification around 24 hours later. Am I headed down the right path? Anyone's expert opinion on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply store a record of your audio file names and a time stamp - you could use core data for this. Then simply retrieve the records that are more than 24 hours old. No need for anything complex like push notifications

Comment: Ah nice. Thanks Paulw11! This will lead me down the right path. Much appreciated.